# Capybara expect *no* alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

Using Capybara, is there a way to expect there to be no alert on the page? I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
click_link('some link')
expect(page).to have_no_alert
```

Or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

No, Capybara does not provide anything like that, and all alert handling methods take the block that would open the alert so writing your own matcher to do it isn't straightforward.

You could do something along the lines of

```
expect do
  accept_alert do # may want to pass a `wait` option to `accept_alert` to shorten how long it will check for an alert to exist
    click_link('some link')
  end
end.to raise_error(Capybara::ModalNotFound)
```

Comment: Okay, for now I'll just test that it reaches the next page.

Comment: @lobati That sounds reasonable - it's usually better to test for a positive outcome rather than a negative one anyway.